# np.sum does not return exact summation

Tags: python, numpy, function-approximation

Consider the following numpy vector of number:

```
a = np.array([.1, .2, .2, .2, .2, .1])
```

Obviously, the sum of these numbers gives 1. However, when computing

```
b = np.sum(a)
```

I get

```
print (b)
0.9999999999999999
```

Could you anyone explain why and how to solve this approximation issue?

Comment: It is nothing to do with approximations (well not really) - Python, C and many other languages use IEE754 Floating Point format, and being a limited precision format, none of the numbers that are in your array can be represented accurately as a binary value.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the machine floating point accuracy. It is explained here in detail: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

You can use the following to fix it:

```
b = round(np.sum(a),5)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change precision choosing a different data type:

```py
n = 1000

print(abs(1 - np.array([1 / n] * n).sum(dtype='float32')))
print(abs(1 - np.array([1 / n] * n).sum(dtype='float64')))
print(abs(1 - np.array([1 / n] * n).sum(dtype='float128')))
```

will produce:

```
1.1920928955078125e-07
4.440892098500626e-16
2.0816681711721685133e-17
```

Comment: This only happens to produce the desired result by sheer fluke. Using float32 actually makes rounding error much worse.